# Convert iterable to RDD

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to save from spark-streaming to couple of elastic-search indices. 
I create pairs of `<key(index), value>`, when I execute groupByKey the result is Tuple of `<key(index), Iterable<value>>` but in order to save to elasticsearch using elasticsearch-spark plugin I need the values as `JavaRDD<value>`.

I know that there is an option of sparkContext.parallelize(list) which creates JavaRDD from list, but this can be executed only on the driver.

Is there another option to create JavaRDD that can be executed on the executor? Or another way that I can achieve `Tuple2<key(index), JavaRDD<value>>` which works on executor?
If not how can I make only the switch of Iterator to JavaRDD on driver and the plugin writing to elasticsearch at the executor?

Thanks,

Daniela

Comment: Ehm, AFAIK, `groupByKey` results in a `JavaPairRDD<K,Iterable<V>>` which is still an `rdd`. Any further processing of the `rdd` is thus executed on the executors and not on the driver.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it has to be possible to have smth like the following

```
JavaPairRDD<Key, Iterable<Value>> pair = ...;
JavaRDD<Iterable<Value>> values = pair.map(t2 -> t2._2());
JavaRDD<Value> onlyValues = values.flatMap(it -> it);
```

Alternative approach would be to

```
JavaPairRDD<Key, Iterable<Value>> pair = ...;
JavaRDD<Key, Value> keyValues = pair.flatMapValues(v1 -> v1);
JavaRDD<Value> values = keyValues.map(t2 -> t2._2());
```

Comment: thanks evgenii, since i need to get from JavaPairRDD<Key, Iterable<Value>> to JavaRDD<Value> that inside foreachRDD the result of JavaRDD<String> values = rdd.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Iterable<String>>, String>) tuple2 -> {
                        final List<String> l = Lists.newArrayList();
                        tuple2._2().forEach(l::add);
                        return l;
                    }); are related to same key?

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question. I will edit my answer, hope it'll be better this time.