# Spark (large dataset) groupBy, sort, and then map

Tags: apache-spark

With a Spark rdd is there a way to groupByKey, then sort within each group, and then map for large datasets. The naive way of doing this maps over each group and creates a list for each group and sorts it. However this creation of a list will potentially cause out of memory problems for groups with many entries. Is there a way to have Spark do the sorting so as to avoid out of memory issues.

Comment: Are you currently getting a memory error?

Comment: Any specific reason for sorting the grouped values? If requirement is to identify top-n or bottom-n values then that can be done by reduceByKey logic.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting a data skew error. This can happen when an executor runs out of memory because too much data is associated with that key. A solution to that problem would be to adjust/play with the number of executors and amount of RAM allocated to each...

However I believe this would be the solution to your problem:

```
JavaPairRDD<Key, Iterable<Value>> pair = ...;
JavaRDD<Iterable<Value>> values = pair.map(t2 -> t2._2());
JavaRDD<Value> onlyValues = values.flatMap(it -> it);
```

source: [Convert iterable to RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823176/convert-iterable-to-rdd)

Please follow up with this possible solution. I am genuinely curious.

Comment: Lines 2 and 3 can be executed at the same time and should be. You can check this in YARN/Spark's job viewer